# OCaml: List.iter starts with next element after match

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I've discovered a weird thing:

In my code, I want to output the data of a list that contains elements of a special type, that consists of another type and `name`.

I've never needed code like this before, so I don't know why it doesn't work or it is prohibited or something like that.

```
List.iter(
    fun x -> (
        fprintf oc "(";
        fprintf oc "asdf";
        match x.kind with
        |Id -> fprintf oc "Id"
        |Op -> fprintf oc "Op"
        |Test -> fprintf oc "Test"
        ;  
        fprintf oc "fdsa";
        fprintf oc "%s" x.name;
        fprintf oc "),";
    )   
)list;
```

asdf and fdsa are test-outputs to see where the problem is.
oc is my output-channel for writing to a file, the rest should be quiet self-explaining for Ocaml-Pros like you :)

Unfortunately, I only get the result like this:
`(asdfId(asdfOp(asdfId`, so it seems, that the execution is stopped after the match, and he continues with the next element of the list.

The expected output would be `(asdfIdfdsatest1),(asdfOpfdsatest2)`...

I can't just move the x.name to the top, since I need the closing bracket

What am I doing wrong, am I missing an error? Does anyone know how to output my data?

Comment: Use a proper OCaml code indentation tool to avoid this kind of bugs, such as ocaml-mode, tuareg-mode or ocp-indent.  They indent the line `fprintf oc "fdsa";` differently from your intention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OCaml `match` has greater priority than `;`. So, you need to wrap your `match` in a pair of parentheses.

Let's try the following in toplevel:

```
> match 0 with
   | 0 -> print_string "zero "
   | _ -> print_string "non-zero";
  print_endline "42";;

Output: zero
```

And now let's add parentheses around the `match` expression:

```
> (match 0 with
   | 0 -> print_string "zero "
   | _ -> print_string "non-zero");
  print_endline "42";;

Output: zero 42
```

*Side note*: in real life it's better to use the `if` expression for that sort of "pattern-matching" on integers.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to indent your code is:

```
List.iter (fun x ->
    fprintf oc "(";
    fprintf oc "asdf";
    match x.kind with
    |Id -> fprintf oc "Id"
    |Op -> fprintf oc "Op"
    |Test -> fprintf oc "Test"
        ;
        fprintf oc "fdsa";
        fprintf oc "%s" x.name;
        fprintf oc "),";
  ) list;
```

Here you can see that the last 3 statements are only executed in the 3rd branch.

To solve this issue, you can rewrite your code this way (the first way is the usual one, from what I have seen:

```
List.iter (fun x ->
    fprintf oc "(";
    fprintf oc "asdf";
    begin match x.kind with
    |Id -> fprintf oc "Id"
    |Op -> fprintf oc "Op"
    |Test -> fprintf oc "Test"
    end;
    fprintf oc "fdsa";
    fprintf oc "%s" x.name;
    fprintf oc "),";
  ) list;
```

or

```
List.iter (fun x ->
    fprintf oc "(";
    fprintf oc "asdf";
    (match x.kind with
     |Id -> fprintf oc "Id"
     |Op -> fprintf oc "Op"
     |Test -> fprintf oc "Test");
    fprintf oc "fdsa";
    fprintf oc "%s" x.name;
    fprintf oc "),";
  ) list;
```